# How to effectively maintain a lot of service endpoint configuration?

Tags: .net, wcf, service

What we have come to is a big system with a lot of services distributed, including WCF windows services, IIS windows services, IIS Web services, self-hosted services, WebApi services and so on. About 30 items in total and it keeps increasing so we ended up with a config nightmare. NServiceBus or any is not an option for our customers so I think we have two options here:

1. Keeping all the config in a single mega-config file. [Here](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2008/11/26/reading-wcf-configuration-from-a-custom-location.aspx) you can find a couple of examples.
2. Design and develop a custom configuration mechanism and keep all the config in a separate DLL which will be referenced in every service and automatically supply/perform all the config stuff. Juval Lowe has a slight notion on this topic in his book (last Edition), unfortunately I can't find an online reference.

I know this question can be closed but if anybody has stuck on this problem ever and has a solution or a good advise would be great. A question itself could be defined as: *Which one of these two options is preferable and why?*

If you're aware of any third-party solution please provide a link.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Take a look at the MS Congifuration Service (part of Stock Trader, but can be used independently).  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dotnetstocktradersampleapplication/threads